# Запреты/разрешения на выполнение команд

Tags: ubuntu

Добрый день уважаемые.Имеем Ubuntu 10.04.1  Помогите решить следующую задачку:Необходимо сделать так, чтобы новый пользовательмог всегда менять свой пароль только с помощью утилиты sudoТо есть нужно запретить выполнение пользователем команды passwdнапрямую, а разрешить её выполнение только через sudoСпасибо всем откликнувшимся :)

Comment: Задачка стоит запретить конкретному пользователю, а не всем кроме рута ;)

Answer (score 1):

я вижу такой вариант:

1. убедитесь что пользователь не    состоит в группах wheel или admin
2. (иначе создайте отдельную группу и   добавьте в нее всех пользователей   которых хотите ограничить в правах)
3. далее

   ```
   sudo -schown root:wheel passwd
   ```

   вы смените владельца файла и группу на root-а и группа wheel
4. далее

   ```
   chmod 4550 passwd
   ```

это разрешит выполнять passwd только руту и членам группы wheel(обычно пользователям вредно состоять в группе wheel/admin и т.п. ;) ).

1. Но вам придется заглянуть еще и в    файл sudo.conf(почитайте man    sudo.conf) и настроить правила    выполнения команды sudo для групп    пользователей

Answer (score 0):

```
# chmod u-s $(which passwd)
```

это запретит запускать всем, кроме рута

Answer (score 0):

```
# chage -m 999999 <username>
```

Comment: хм...  сработало, но не до конца. Прямой вызов passwd недоступен, через sudo меняю пас - ответ системы саксесфул, но на самом деле пас остаётся старым :(